# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "query_call_back(callback_func_type)"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, armv7, il2cpp

I've a problem to build iOS project after recently upgraded my project from **Unity 5.6.4 to 2018.4.19f1**. Everything is ok to export, build and run on my device, but if I archive the exported project, then the error occurs:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "query_call_back(callback_func_type)", referenced from:
>   il2cpp::vm::MetadataCache::Initialize() in
>   libil2cpp.a(External_il2cpp_il2cpp_libil2cpp_vm_6.o)
>   il2cpp::vm::MetadataCache::Initialize() in
>   libil2cpp.a(External_il2cpp_il2cpp_libil2cpp_vm_6.o) ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Environments:**

- Unity 2018.4.19f1
- Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Appreciate if anyone can help!

Solution:
After hours of upgrade unity again to 2019.3.4f1 and fix mirror error.
Finally, Xcode archive the project successful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, try to upgrade Unity to the latest stable version.

Comment: I'm already upgraded to 2018.4.19f1(LTS), do you means i could try to upgrade to a  newer version such as 2019.3.4f1?